# Single ADBannerViewDelegate for multiple views

Tags: ios, iad, adbannerview

I'm trying to implement simgle AdBanner instance for multiple views in an iOS app. For implementing AdbannerDelegate in a viewController one has to do
    bannerview.delegate= self;
where bannerview is an instance of AdBannerView. This delegate method however has to be implemented in every viewController which amounts up to a lot of repeating code. How can I make up a simple class that implements all delegate methods and then I call use them in every viewController.

Answer (score 2):

I think the viewControllers you are using are subclasses of UIViewController.
And you are saying all the viewControllers have the same delegate methods.

So,what i want to do is create new ViewController class (`UIDelgateViewController`) by SubClassing `UIViewController` and add all delegate methods there , and have **all the other viewControllers subclass UIDelgateViewController**.

The code goes like this,
**.h file->**

```
@interface UIDelegateViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property ADBannerView *bannerView;
@end
```

**.m file ->**

```
#import "UIDelegateViewController.h"

@interface UIDelegateViewController ()

@end

@implementation UIDelegateViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    _bannerView.delegate =self;
}

-(void)bannerDelegateMethod{

}
```

Now your Some viewController ->

```
#import "UIDelegateViewController.h"

@interface SomeViewController : UIDelegateViewController

@end


#import "SomeViewController.h"

@interface SomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation SomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
    self.bannerView.frame = ..../
}
```

Comment: Tried. It works good but somewhere in app running the app crashes giving exc_bad_access error. I think some uiviewController goes missing in the way.

Comment: Thnaks a lot for the code. I' using different subviews in viewControllers like UITableView and UIScrollview. How can I incorporate all those changes (resizing differnet subviews) in that single AdBannerDelegate method?

Comment: you dont need to write them in delegate method unless those tableViews and scrollViews are common for most of the controllers.If they are common, just create them in UIDelegateVC like adbannerView . If they are not common, they in the viewController which subclasses UIDelegateVC, create them in viewDidLoad, and resize in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep always on the screen the same banner while navigating and changing views, you should consider to use [View Controller containtment API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)
A great example is that [remarkable sample code written by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html), that shows how to keep the same banner instance while moving in a tabbar or navigation controller. It could be also a great start for you project.